# check upload status with youtube api?

Tags: python, autohotkey, youtube-data-api

i am working on a ahk script which does some stuff and then uploads a video to youtube.

since the browser automation is lacking for ahk i had to look for another option and i discovered the youtube api and the yt_upload.py.
https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/uploading_a_video

i got the python script to work but i don't know how to let my ahk script know when the python script is done with the upload.

so is there maybe another api option to check for the video upload status?
is there  another way i could achieve this without using a webbrowser?

Comment: Maybe print something after its uploaded as python waits for everything. You can send a signal from there. I dont know how AHK works so I can just tell you that after the video is uploaded the next line will come into play automatically. If it doesn't try running it from the shell because there is most defnitely an error cancelling the program

Answer (score 0):

Just execute the python script in a command window from Autohotkey and wait until the command window no longer exists. By default the command window stays open until the .py file finishes and then closes. That is pretty much what I do with my similar [gmail script here](https://steventaitinger.wordpress.com/2015/09/03/send-gmail-message-using-gmail-api-and-python). Except I don't explicitly wait for the command window to close since I don't care for my purposes.

Something like...

```
WinWaitClose , cmd_ahk_id
```

If python is not waiting for the upload status to change yet then you need check something like [processingStatus](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos)

Comment: well the problem is the python.exe cmd windows stays open after the upload :(